# Audio resampling in Android

Tags: android, audio

I have audio decoder that sends me back chunks of decoded audio data with sample rate 44100, I need to resample to 48000 just as I received it. Is there a way to use native audio resampler (I mean AudioResampler.h from android source) or libraries for that?

I tried to use JSSRC library but it is too slow and greedy for just in time audio processing.

Comment: Have you managed to do this task?

Comment: No, I didn't. I used native libresample library with jni implementation instead. https://github.com/intervigilium/libresample/tree/master/jni/resample